# Symfony 2 - links from microsoft office redirect to login page

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 version 2.5.5 and have a problem, links from another place works fine but if i copy this links to the word or excel site redirected me to login page.

Log:

```
security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token []
security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated)
security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point []
```

I fixed it so:

```
   if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'ms-office')!==false){
        die();
}
```

in app_dev.php

But i think this is not best solution. Maybe you advise me another idea?

Comment: Do you mean the page is displayed within word or excel application, ie not in browser?

Comment: Page displayed in browser

Comment: That's quite weird, I wonder why you see ms-office as user agent. Doesn't the location point to local temporary file?

Comment: if i pass the link from word i have  [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; ms-office) if i pass form browser [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)

Comment: And what is in the browser's location bar?